# How to make "click" and "hasFocus" events firing at same time work together?

Tags: knockout.js

I'm creating a knockout component composed of a single input field where one can search for users.
I'm using the `click` event to get the selected user from a list, and I'd like to do some stuff, like hide the list, if the input loses the focus (aka they clicked somewhere else).

The problem is, when I click on an element from the list, the `hasFocus` event fires and, somehow, prevents the `click` event from firing.
I don't get why, since they are siblings, not father-child events.

I've managed to make it work by adding a timeout in the subscribe function to `hasFocus` but I don't think it's the right way to do it.

Is this the only way to do it? Having such timeouts to make your code work is bad practice, right?

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/57kxyud9/

- As it is, only the `click` event is enabled and it works fine.
- You can enable the `hasFocus` event-subscribe and you may notice it stops saving user's info.
- You can then enable the timeout inside the `hasFocus.subscribe` and the program works again.

Should I also embed code snippets in this post?

I'd like to be able to save the user when I click on it even with the `input_hasFocus.subscribe` active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong in adding a `setTimeout` to change the order of `subscribe` per se. Because `rateLimit` is a valid concept in knockout. But, one `subscribe` updating another `observable`, which in turn triggers it's `subscribe` and so on, seems unnecessary. So, if you want an `observable` which is derived from other observables, you can make it a `computed` property instead of updating it's value from all the observables' subscriber's it's dependent upon.

For ex,

- `show_matchingUsers` is dependent upon `input_hasFocus` and whether any `selection` is made.
- `matches` is entirely dependent upon `selection`

So, you can make these as [`computed`](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) observables:

```js
var vm = function() {
  var self = this;

  self.users = [{"username":ko.observable("Alice")},{"username":ko.observable("Bob")},{"username":ko.observable("User 3")},{"username":ko.observable("User 4")},{"username":ko.observable("User 5")}];

  self.selection = ko.observable();
  self.chosenUser = ko.observable();
  self.input_hasFocus = ko.observable(false);
  self.matches = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.show_matchingUsers = ko.observable(false);

  // gets computed every time "selection" cahnges
  self.matches = ko.computed(function() {
    let matches = [],
      val = self.selection();

    if (!val) {
      return matches;
    }
    /*for each item in the array...*/
    for (i = 0; i < self.users.length; i++) {
      /*check if the item starts with the same letters as the text field value:*/
      if (self.users[i].username().substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
        matches.push(self.users[i]);
      }
    }

    return matches;
  })

  // gets computed every time "input_hasFocus" and "selection" cahnges
  self.show_matchingUsers = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.input_hasFocus() && self.selection()
  }).extend({ rateLimit: 200 });

  self.select_thisUser = function(u) {
    self.chosenUser(u);
    self.selection(u.username());
  };
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<br/> Selected User:
<!-- ko with:chosenUser -->
<span data-bind="text:username"></span>
<!-- /ko -->

<hr style="border-color:white;background-color:white;color:white;border-style:solid;" />

<div class="autocomplete">
  <input data-bind="textInput: selection, hasFocus:input_hasFocus" autocomplete="off" type="search" placeholder="Search" />
  <div data-bind="visible:show_matchingUsers,foreach:matches" class="autocomplete-items">
    <div data-bind="click:function(){$parent.select_thisUser(this);}">
      <span data-bind="text:username"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm guessing `focus` is fired before `click` event. That's why the `matches` are hidden before they are clicked. So, we can add a [`rateLimit`](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/rateLimit-observable.html) of 200 seconds. This is basically instructing knockout to wait 200ms, so that `click` event goes through before `show_matchingUsers` is computed again.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ncL6vd7x/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. While this indeed works, I'm afraid it doesn't fit my needs. Unfortunately I need to do some more stuff when the input loses focus, I just skipped that part in the question 'cause I didn't thought they were necessary.. should I expand/update my question or should I create a new one?

Comment: @oust Please update the fiddle. I feel you can still do all those things inside `self.input_hasFocus.subscribe()`

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was trying to create a working fiddle based on your hints and eventually solved the problem! Thanks for your help :)